# Meteor Accounts + Apple Sign In

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor, oauth, meteor-accounts

Is “Sign In with Apple” supported by Meteor Accounts? I cant find it in https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loginWith but will be required by any new/updated iOS app that uses Facebook/Google/Twitter authentication (see https://techcrunch.com/2019/06/07/answers-to-your-burning-questions-about-how-sign-in-with-apple-works/)

So, if not supported (yet) how will you get your next cordova/iOS app approved by apple, if using Meteor accounts package with Facebook/Google/etc authentication?

Comment: I think you should raise an issue here : https://github.com/meteor/meteor
Alternatively, Auth0 provides the ability to sign in with apple, and you can bridge it to meteor user accounts (some packages exist : https://atmospherejs.com/?q=auth0 )

Comment: Asked also in https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-accounts-and-appleid/50079 but no answer yet. I'll update both as soon as there is an answer.